# C# Set File Size

Tags: c#

I have an app which I use for downloads. I've noticed that if I let it create the placeholder file, then pause it, it still shows the placeholder file size as the size that it *will be*, not the size that it *is*. And, looking at the free space on my hard drive, I can see it really is taking up that much space. That got me curious as to how they did that; I've been trying to figure out how to set the file size. I've found lots of information on how to *get* the file size, but none on how to set it. Nothing I've tried has worked. Curious if anyone knows if this can be done in C#?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+Set+File+Size , https://www.google.com/#q=C%23+set+file+size ?

Comment: Wait a minute.... Glitch in Bing? I actually searched for that exact search string and not one of those results came up. How does *that* work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FileStream.SetLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the given value is less than the current length of the stream, the stream is truncated. In this scenario, if the current position is greater than the new length, the current position is moved to the last byte of the stream. If the given value is larger than the current length of the stream, the stream is expanded, and the current position remains the same. If the stream is expanded, the contents of the stream between the old and the new length are undefined.

Comment: One has to be careful when using FileStream.SetLength(). After a write to the stream, a setLength(0) will flush the internal buffer of the previous write to the file and the resulting file will not be 0 !

Comment: @PeterHuber: Yikes... would calling `Flush` before that fix it? (Admittedly it would be quite odd to write to the stream and *then* truncate the file anyway...)

Comment: I don't understand FileStream in detail. I first noticed the problem in my code, then checked http://referencesource.microsoft.com. There you can see:
// Handle buffering updates.
if (_writePos > 0) {
  FlushWrite(false); 
}
This passes the FileStream buffer to the OS.
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,212c0536642e78d6

Comment: You are right, adding Flush() before SetLength() solves the problem. In the following code, only d is written to the file. Without Flush, cd gets written. `streamWriter.WriteLine("c"); 
streamWriter.Flush();
fileStream.SetLength(0);
streamWriter.WriteLine("d");`